# I'm trying to make a clock pulse generator but when I run the simulation nothing happens

Tags: basic, breadboard

I am new to using circuit/breadboard simulation apps.  When I run the simulation nothings happens. Here is the original schematic.

Edit: I'm using 74HC00.
Also I learned how to use Virtual Breadboard more, so here is my final submission, sorry for the inconvenience I'm new to this site and to electrical engineering as a whole.

Here is what's supposed to happen:

- I'm trying to create clock pulses, One LED should be off while the other is on, the problem is both of them are on.

I tried to measure the voltage on the inputs of the gate 1 and 3.  It's 0, I don't know what's blocking the current.

[image]
[image]

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. You are definitely using a 74LS00 aren't you, not for example a 74HC00 or 74HCT00 ?

Comment: Schmidt trigger usually used.

Comment: @TonyM What's the difference ? All I know is that I should be using a 7400.

Comment: The input and output stages are very different. LS can operate in a linear mode whereas HC and HCT, for example, won't. You can find plenty already written about that on the internet. Question is: which one are you using? (Please edit your question to add this new information, don't put it into comments. Otherwise, readers have to piece the actual question together.)

Comment: 7400 is yet another part.  If they were fully interchangeable, there'd only be one sort.  Instead, there's 7400, 74LS, 74F, 74L, 74S, 74C, 74HC, 74HCT, 74AC, 74ACT, et cetera, et cetera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first important thing that you need to know here is that you are using digital logic gates as analog parts.  You're making them into amplifiers in this case.  This isn't a bad thing, per se, but you're definitely straying off of the applications that the datasheets support.  So you have to dig deep into how the parts really work under the hood.

The second important thing that you need to know is that even when you *are* using them purely as digital gates, 74HCxx parts are not a direct replacement for 74LS** parts.  You can make it work sometimes, but mixing them gets problematical if you want full speed or glitch resistance, and you *definitely* can't freely exchange them in an analog circuit.

So -- as Tony Steward pointed out -- you're biasing the parts incorrectly.  In the picture, I've showed the difference.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAT09Y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note the wording in the text -- in the case of the 74LS00, I've said "analog range", where in the case of the 74HC00, I've said "illegal range".  This is because by the time that the 74HC parts came out, transistors were smaller and cheaper.  The 74LS parts have fewer stages of amplification internally.  They have significantly lower gain than the 74HC parts, which makes them much better behaved than a 74HC when you're misusing them as analog amplifiers.

On the other hand, the 74HC parts have enough gain that they tend to "snap" from off to on -- while they have a gap between their guarantee-high input and their guaranteed-low input, most of this gap in taken up by uncertainty in just where the threshold is, not an area where there's a nice soft transition from "off" to "on".

This difference is pronounced enough that the 74HCU04 exists -- this is a 74xx04-style inverting buffer, that is intentionally designed to have a better-behaved analog region.  It was introduced by digital designers who knew how to use a 74xx04 to make a crystal oscillator, and didn't want to specify just one 74C04 or 74LS04, or whatever.

So if you *do* change to the recommended "analog" version of the 74HC00, you may find that the circuit is still poorly behaved.  Where I would expect the 'LS version to settle into a ring oscillator, the 'HC version may end up in a mode where each stage is madly oscillating by itself, against the lead inductance or pin capacitance of the part, rather than going through those electrolytic capacitors as you expect.

If your goal is to just learn stuff -- plow ahead!  If your goal is product design, or to make a reliable hobby project, I strongly suggest that you either use 74LS00 parts as originally intended, or 74C00 parts using my "74HC00" circuit, or better yet, use a circuit based on something intended for the job, like comparators or a 555 timer.

Comment: I wanna Learn more about the stuff you talked about, I did this circuit without any knowledge about "analog range" and the deference between 74xx04 ICs, can you recommend me a book or something ?

Answer (score 0):

The input bias current for a 7400 is different than a 74LS00 and a 74HC00(cmos).

When using TTL select , I think (back a few decades), select half of the nominal Iil logic current for input low to put it in the linear gain zone.  Measure the Vinput to expect two diode drops or 1.2V or slightly less, which is the actual threshold for ALL TTL logic and RS-232.

Since TTL is asymmetric the low level draws and drives more current. (10:1 for all families by designs

- Therefore put the resistor or anode of both LEDs to 5V and drive the low side instead.

Looking up the datasheet to refresh my memory the 74LS00 is specified as 400mV at -0.4 mA which appears as a 1K input resistance, but nonlinear due to 2 Vbe drops. So to get near 1 to 1.2V change Rs on the input to 0V so that the output just toggles or saturates to either rail with noise. Repeat for both. This will be temperature sensitive.

The other approach using 2V output hi and 0.7V low drawing LED current from the low side you can try a negative feedback resistor instead on each gate to do the same causing the output to oscillate. With a smaller output swing a lower feedback (2V-1.2V/200uA= 4k) around this value or so.

Since e-caps can only tolerate about 10% of their rated voltage in reverse worst case, ensure the voltage rating is adequate.

For 4000 series CMOS, you would use a feedback R >100k to 10M instead of a shunt R of 10K to 0V.